# Flex Hero Mobile, sharing data when popping views

Tags: android, apache-flex, mobile, air, adobe

We can pass data to the next view while using navigator.pushview, but the data is lost when the back button is clicked (popview).

I have views that make remote calls and I want to keep the data when the user navigates back to the view using the back button so I don't have to make a remote call again.

Is there a way to set a global variable that's accessible from all views, or a way to retain data when a user navigates back to a view using the back button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the good way to do that is overriding the createReturnObject method in your view.

Read [this](http://remotesynthesis.com/post.cfm/passing-data-on-pop-methods-in-mobile-flex) for more info

Also, the data property is persisted and re-assigned when the view is re-instancied, so you can store info in it

Answer (score 3):

Ok figured it out.

I can set variables in the main application and access them from any view using

`this.parentApplication.myVar;`

Comment: Tou shouldn't do that way, please see my answer

Comment: I am not a big fan of this approach, as it is really just a global variable... which comes with all of the history of problems that global variables brings.

Comment: Im sure global variables are "bad", but even worse is passing *all* of your global data to views even if they dont need it!

Answer (score 1):

You can declare the global variables in the main application mxml file. For example, you define a variable student in the main application, then you can access it in any other view by using  **FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.student**

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to assign your value as a property to **data** member of the view.

But sometimes I use **data** for something else (for example as a dataprovider for a List in the view) and then I create static variables in my views and store my stuff there.